# Custom jquery validate messages for all errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I specify a custom error message for each error type, like required and date. I want a different message depending on the error type.

I have a field that looks like this

`<input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" class="required date" />`

my error messages look like this

`This field is required` or  `Please enter a valid date`

How can I make it say the following

`Date of birth is required` and `Please enter a valid date for Date of Birth`

This is what I'm using

```
var validator = $("form:first").validate({
    errorClass: 'Input_State_Error',
    rules: {
        dateOfBirth: "required date"
    },
    messages: {
        dateOfBirth: "Please enter your date of birth"
    },
    // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                
        error.appendTo($('#ctl00_lblMessage'));
    },
    // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        // set &nbsp; as text for IE
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following jquery `date()` [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) for Validation Plugin, i guess you suggest this:

```
var validator = $("form:first").validate({
    ...
    messages: {
        dateOfBirth: {
            required: "Date of birth is required",
            date: "Please enter a valid date for Date of Birth"
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! I thought I was out of luck when I didn't get any answers yesterday.